# Search and get all child nodes of XML node base on attribute id

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a sample XML like this:

```
<doc>
    <customer id="1">
      <first>
        <fullname>John Doe 1</fullname>
        <contact>011-1111111</contact>
        <title>Lorem</title>
      </first>
      <second>
        <fullname>John Doe 2</fullname>
        <contact>012-2222222</contact>
        <title>Lorem</title>
      </second>
    </customer>       
</doc>
```

My question is how can I get all the child node inside first and second based on the customer id. So far this is what i have tried but i have no idea how to continue it.

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("sampleXML.xml");
 var controls = from str in doc.Elements("customer")
                           where str.Attribute("id").Value == 1
                           select str;
```

If I am able to get the data, how can i display the result? By using foreach loop? Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I am quite new to c# and linq.

Comment: Yes you can use a foreach loop.  For debugging with linq it is easier to see results using .ToList() with parenthesis : (from str .....select str).ToList();  You can then use controls.Elements().Select(x => new { fullname = (string)x.Element("fullname")).ToList();  Using Elements() will get both first and second elements,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `XElement.Load("xmlPath")` to load the xml and get all the customer elements the filter out based on the attribute. Loop through the each nodes and print.

```
        XElement xelement = XElement.Load("sampleXml.xml");
        var customers = xelement.Elements("customer").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("id").Value == "1");
        foreach (XElement customer in customers.Nodes())
        {
            var fullName = customer.Element("fullname").Value;
            var contact = customer.Element("contact").Value;
            var title = customer.Element("title").Value;
        }
```

Comment: I have updated the answer. You can use this code. It is more efficient than the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

you can use below code to get information in `first` tag.

```
var first = doc.Root.Elements("customer").Elements("first").Elements();
```

Comment: Can you show me how to display all the value inside <first> also?

Answer (score 1):

You can use xpath for finding the element with attribute value.

Here is an example

```
    string xml= "your xml string";
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    var nodes = doc.SelectSingleNode("/doc/customer[@id='1']").ChildNodes;
```